# Simplest way to convert this array in to the specified one using Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, performance

I have this String Json Payload

```
[
   "key1":{
      "atr1":"key1",
      "atr2":"value1",
      "atr3":"value2",
      "atr4":"value3,
      "atr5":"value4"
   },
   "key2":{
      "atr1":"key2",
      "atr2":"value5",
      "atr3":"value6",
      "atr4":value7,
      "atr5":"value8"
   }
]
```

and I want it to be converted in to the following format using Java

```
[
  {
      "atr2":"value1",
      "atr3":"value2",
      "atr4":"value3,
      "atr5":"value4"
   },
  {
      "atr2":"value5",
      "atr3":"value6",
      "atr4": "value7",
      "atr5":"value8"
   }
]
```

What would be the simplest way of transforming this ?

Comment: `value7` is not a valid json value. Did you mean `"value7"` or `7`?

Comment: Do you want to remove `"atr1":"key1"` and `"atr1":"key2"` ?

Comment: It should be "value7" sorry I fixed it

Comment: Yes it needs to be removed as well

Comment: @CharithJayasanka no, you didn’t fix it. Please check again.

Comment: Do you want to fix a String that is this json, or do you want to fix the object the json was deserialised to?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, because the example below is **not** valid `json`.
Check it out using this JSON validator.

If you paste this in (I've fixed some basic errors with lack of quotes)

```
{
  {
      "atr2":"value1",
      "atr3":"value2",
      "atr4":"value3",
      "atr5":"value4"
   },
  {
      "atr2":"value5",
      "atr3":"value6",
      "atr4":"value7",
      "atr5":"value8"
   }
}
```

You will get these errors ...

[image]

It can work if you change the target schema to something like this by using a `json-array` to contain your data.

```
[
  {
      "atr2":"value1",
      "atr3":"value2",
      "atr4":"value3",
      "atr5":"value4"
   },
  {
      "atr2":"value5",
      "atr3":"value6",
      "atr4":"value7",
      "atr5":"value8"
   }
]
```

If this works for you, then this problem can easily be solved by using the `ObjectMapper` class.

1. You use it to deserealize the original JSON into a class, which has two fields "key1" and "key2"
2. Extract the values of these fields and then just store them in an array ...
3. Serialize the array using the `ObjectMapper`.

Here a [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial), which explains how to use the `ObjectMapper` class to achieve the goals above.

**EDIT:**

So you'll need the following classes to solve the problem ...

Stores the object data

```
class MyClass {
   String atr2;
   String art3;
}
```

Then you have a container class, which is used to store the initial json.

```
class MyClassContainer {
  MyClass key1;
  MyClass key2;
}
```

Here's how you do the parse from the original json to `MyClassContainer`

```
var mapper = new ObjectMapper()
var json = //Get the json String somehow
var myClassContainer =  mapper.readValue(json,MyClassContainer.class)
var mc1 = myClassContainer.getKey1();
var mc2 = myClassContainer.getKey2();
var myArray = {key1, key2}
var resultJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(myArray)
```

Comment: At least converting in to an array is fine

Comment: Cool. Then ObjectMapper will do everything you want.

Comment: I've edited it in to an array

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will correct the JSON into a valid one (which involves replacing the surrounding square braces with curly ones, and correct enclosure of attribute values within quotes), here's a simpler way which involves only a few lines of core logic.

```
try{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure( DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false );
    HashMap<String, Data> map = mapper.readValue( jsonString, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Data>>(){} );
        
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString( map.values() );
    System.out.println( json );
}
catch( JsonProcessingException e ){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

- `jsonString` above is your original JSON corrected and valid JSON input.
- Also notice the setting of `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` to `false` to allow `atr1` to be ignored while deserializing into `Data`.

Since we are completely throwing away `attr1` and its value, the `Data` class will represent all fields apart from that.

```
private static class Data{
    private String atr2;
    private String atr3;
    private String atr4;
    private String atr5;
}
```